# Node.js - generate ugly class names

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, npm

Is there a way to generate ugly class names? I mean if there's a plugin that I could use to replace `.top-header` class with `.a9ev` in my css. Also, would be great if class name in my html was also changed

How big sites like facebook or google do this?

Comment: You just need to look up minifiers or "uglifiers" for HTML/CSS. A quick Google search yielded some results for me.

Comment: Sorry, I had to laugh about "ugly classnames". What you might want to look for are "obfuscators" or "minifiers".

Comment: Keep in mind that if you reference any class names in Javascript, then you either need to also change them in your scripts or you need to not shorten the ones that are referenced via Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some luck using one of these:

- https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/
- http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/
- https://cssminifier.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier
- https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher
- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
- http://minifycode.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-minify
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-cssnames

Some of those are general tools and some of those like `gulp-minify-cssnames` are very specific tools that do one thing only - like minifying the CSS class names and IDs in this case.

Make sure that you use the same versions of minified names across all of your code, i.e. that you reference the classes in HTML, CSS and in JavaScript by the same (minified - or uglyfied) names.

Comment: that's the answer that I accept. You helped me a lot! Thank u ;)